# Prevent charging when connecting to notebook via USB

Tags: charging, android-14

I have Android 14 on a Google Pixel 7, and whenever I connect my phone with my notebook via USB it starts charging the battery. I'd rather to choose not to charge the phone. Is there any way to prevent this? Ideally, I don't want to root my phone.

These are the options I see (sorry, only German):

[image]

Comment: It is an English only website.  However the options match my phone.  Have you tried selecting any other option under **Use USB for** than *Charging phone only*?

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot is only for illustration. I haven't tried another option from the "Use USB for..." because they seem not to imply that it **won't** charge. But let me try. Because PTP and MIDI might be worth a try.

Comment: To my knowledge you can not prevent charging when there is an USB connection on a stock device. The only options are rooting or prevent charging on hardware level.